# Eclipse. ClassNotFoundException but I do know that class exists

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, rcp

I added myLibrary.jar in project BuildPath and try to call static method from myLibrary.jar myClass but have exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: application/Application
    at rcp.handlers.RunGenerationHandler.execute(RunGenerationHandler.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.Application cannot be found by rcp_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 46 more
```

I'm sure that class exists in Library.
I try to rebuild myLibrary.jar and add in project again but problem still stays.
Below is the code where I try to call static method from my class:

```
import application.Application;
...

if (generationString != null){
    Application.main(generationString);
}
```

Application - class in myLibrary.jar

[image: Screenshot with package tree]

ldl = myLibrary

**UPDATE**
I'm really such a slowpoke=(
In RCP applications libraries attaching in MANIFEST.MF
Example:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,/directory/myLibrary.jar
```

Comment: remove your jar from the buildpath, refresh your project , and add once again. Sometimes, external jar do not get reflected.

Comment: Restart Eclipse, clean, build.

Comment: Have you checked that the jar is in your project classpath? Are you using an IDE or compiling from cmd?

Comment: Please post your code where you are making the call.

Comment: Are you really sure? Use an unzip utility (or `jar -tf <jar-file>` command) to check if such class is in jar.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala
It didn't help.

Comment: @Albert I'm really sure. I wrote it library and static method which I'm trying to call.

Comment: @Dagriel I'm using Eclipse IDE. Yes, I checked.

Comment: Also, make sure you are referencing the correct version of the jar file and not an old one that might not contain the class you want/need.

Comment: Is the method you're trying to call public?

Comment: Is it in appropriate location in jar? I mean, `application/Application.class`. Can you show the contents of jar with paths? At least, related ones.

Comment: @Tavo version is actual.

Comment: @Dagriel Yes. Method is public.

Comment: @Albert I havn't rep for post picture. I'm sure method is static and public and class exists.

Comment: Did you also put **external libraries** into the **myLibrary.jar** file?
I had a similar problem when I tried to **merge multiple jars** built with **OSGi** into one jar. 
If so, better separate those dependencies.

Comment: You can upload into an image hosting like [imageshack](http://imageshack.us/) or [postimage](http://postimage.org/), and then post the link. Nevertheless, take a look at `.classpath` file to check if it has a _classpathentry_ to your jar.

Comment: @Albert I added screenshot with package tree and checked .classpath. I found this string: `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Alexander/workspace/rcp/lib/ldl.jar"/>`

Comment: @AleksandrKorotkov, although that picture belongs to the project itself, not to `library.jar`, I suppose such library has the same contents and structure, right? It looks ok. I don't know what's the problem. You can try eliminate jar from `build-path`, and refer directly to the project (without the library).

Comment: @Albert I have sloved the problem. I wrote all library paths in MANIFEST.MF `Bundle-ClassPath: .,/directory/myLibrary.jar`. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @AleksandrKorotkov, Glad to hear that! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Library is also a RCP-Plugin you have to add it in the dependencies of your plugin.xml in your project.
In the Library plugin.xml you have to export the package where the class is in.